# jQuery UI droppable limit to last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to drop an element on top of multiple droppable DIVs, but I have a problem with event bubbling. The droppable event gets executed multiple times, based on how many elements are layered on top of each other. I would like to execute it only for the last/top element.

**Please see [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KB47q/).**

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="box droppable">1
    <div id="2" class="box droppable">2
        <div id="3" class="box droppable">3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="drag" class="draggable">Drag me! I dare you!</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            content = $('#output').html();
            $('#output').html(content + "Dropped "+ui.draggable.prop('id') + " on " +$(this).attr('id')+".<br/>");   
        }
    });
});
```

When you drop the draggable on element 1 it will say that you dropped it on 1. That's correct. If you drop it on element 3, it will say you dropped it on 1,2,3. **I need to limit this only to the third/top-most element.** How can I achieve this please?

*I've experienced this in the past in a different situation, where it required a confirmation, so the droppable target ID could be stored in an invisible field (the last value), but I need to make it directly this time, no workarounds :(*

Thanks!

Comment: If you need to refresh the content after each drag and drop the you can remove `content = $('#output').html();` as well as remove `content ` from this line `$('#output').html(content + .....`.

Comment: @Pavlo I need to fire the event only for the last element (with ID 3).

Comment: What about just remove `droppable` class from `div`'s where `id=1 and id=2` ?

Comment: @Pavlo I can't, they have to be droppable as well.

Comment: Paste the following code in your `drop` event: `if($(this).prop('id') == 3){ $('#output').html("Dropped"); } else{ $('#output').html(""); }`. Is that what you need?

Comment: @Pavlo thank you for your help, but this needs to by dynamic of course, I can't just put ifs regarding specific elements in it. I am asking about the implementation of the `drop` event. I need to prevent propagation somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I only weren't so lazy to browse around the documentation for a bit. The solution to this problem [can be found here](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation). By specifying the `greedy` option user can limit the affected droppable elements.

In other words

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy: true, //limit to only top-most droppable element
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        content = $('#output').html();
        $('#output').html(content + "Dropped "+ui.draggable.prop('id') + " on " +$(this).attr('id')+".<br/>");   
    }
});
```

Comment: As for me, this answer differs of your question. Anyway, glad you found the way how to fix your problem.